# React How to fix Failed prop type - Invalid prop of type string expected object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm building a small `react`-app where among other things users can register, login and so on. For the Login, I have created a loginform with additional error validation, coming from the backend. Now when I try to login, and by purpose enter wrong credentials, nothing happens (which in some reason is right) but instead of my error messages, the console tells me about an error:

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `errors` of type `string` supplied to `Login`, expected `object`
```

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import classnames from "classnames";
import { loginUser } from "../../actions/authActions";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
     email: "",
     password: "",
     errors: {}
   };

   this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
   this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/mysite");
    }

    if (nextProps.errors) {
     this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
    }
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const userData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };

    this.props.loginUser(userData);
  }

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="login">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
              <h1 className="display-4 text-center">Log In</h1>
               <p className="lead text-center">Sign in to your account</p>
               <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                 <div className="form-group">
                  <input
                   type="email"
                     className={classnames("form-control form-control-lg", {
                  "is-invalid": errors.email
                   })}
                  placeholder="Email Address"
                  name="email"
                  value={this.state.email}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                 />
                 {errors.email && (
                   <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.email}</div>
                 )}
               </div>
               <div className="form-group">
                 <input
                  type="password"
                  className={classnames("form-control form-control-lg", {
                  "is-invalid": errors.password
                  })}
                  placeholder="Password"
                  name="password"
                  value={this.state.password}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                 />
                {errors.password && (
                  <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.password}</div>
                )}
              </div>
              <input type="submit" className="btn btn-info btn-block mt-4" />
             </form>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
 { loginUser }
)(Login);
```

I have no clue why that error appears!? Can someone help me out?

Comment: Login requires the prop 'errors' to be passed in, and it must be an object. `errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired` - this error tells you a string is being pass in instead. Can you show the code where Login is being used?

Answer (score 3):

You are passing string as an error instead of object in the props for the Login component. Try console.log of "errors" in the component where Login component is rendered to see what value is getting set.

Comment: Empty errors object should be printed in the console as {} instead of an empty string. May be you can have a check if its an empty string send it as {} in the component where Login component is rendered.

Answer (score 3):

PropTypes expecting an object because of your propTypes definition

```
  erros: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
```

Use:

```
Login.propTypes = {
  loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

If it's no required your also have to define a defaultProp:

```
Login.propTypes ={
  errors: PropTypes.string,
}

Login.defaultProps = {
  errors: '',
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Make sure your link is not misspelled,

```
export const loginUser=(userData)=>dispatch=>{
  axios.post('/api/users/login',userData)
```

not

```
export const loginUser=(userData)=>dispatch=>{
  axios.post('/api/user/login',userData)
```

users not user

Comment: To maintain sanity and rationalism, pls make sure to also comment the reason of why this answer is downvoted. This is important to maintain healthy communication channel.